# Update two tables with a single query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to update some information which are stored in two tables. To update one of the table, a JOIN with the other table must be done. I was wondering, if I can update both with a single query. Some posts suggested using a trigger. I was hoping there's another way, since I will have to do it in C#. Also I saw other posts saying it's possible using something like this:

```
update pd, pr
set pd.Name = 'Test',
pr.Date = '2012-07-31',
from prDetail pd
left join pr on pd.ID = pr.ID
where pd.Code = '45007'
and pr = '2019'
and pr.Item = '1'
```

This is not working for me (it's showing this error: `Incorrect syntax near ','`). Can this be achieved in some way?

Comment: You can write a stored procedure.

Comment: Also (even if an update could affect multiple tables, which it can't), your left join is not really a left join. You have a where clause against columns in the right table, which effectively makes this a right join. You'll need two statements to accomplish this anyway, but I suggest some research on how inner and outer joins work first...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

You can only update one table at a time.

Separate your update into two update queries, and if necessary, wrap them in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As @podiluska said you can only update one table at a time. And you can also use transaction for executing both query with a single transaction.

Else,
If your table/relation has dependency (foreign key and primary key ) relation , then you can use `cascade` options.

Else,

You can use `Trigger`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to update two at a time but you may consider wrapping it up in a stored procedure and calling that instead.  You should try to avoid triggers for something like this if possible.